# Visual Basic 6.0 ADODB command to variable

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vb6

Here's the code

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Nirvana.mdb" & "; Persist Security Info=False;"
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.CommandText = "Select [Last Name] From Accounts Where [First Name]=@FN"
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.Parameters.Item("@FN").Value = txtFirstName.Text
cmd.Execute
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
conn.Close
```

How do i pass the result of this query to a variable in Visual Basic 6.0 ?

Answer (score 5):

Results are stored in a Record Set, create one:

```
dim rs as ADODB.RecordSet
```

Then instead of `cmd.execute` use:

```
rs.open cmd

if not rs.eof then
   ''//got rows 
   msgbox "first row, first col=" & rs.collect(0)
   ...
```